# Why my multi javascript array can no pass the data throw ajax?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery

```
var model = new Array();

function saveItem(id){ 

   var title = $("#inputTitle_"+id).val();

   var url   = $("#inputPicurl_"+id).val();

   var content = $("#content-editor-"+id).html();

   model[id] = new Array();

   model[id]['inputTitle'] = $("#inputTitle_"+id).val();

   model[id]['inputPicurl'] = $("#inputPicurl_"+id).val();

   model[id]['author'] = $("#author_"+id).val();

   model[id]['content'] = $("#content-editor-"+id).html();

   $("#title_"+id).text(model[id]['inputTitle']); 

   console.log(model);
}

 $("#submit_form").click(function(){

       $.ajax({
        url:'materials/addpics',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data:model,
        traditional:'true',
        success:function(data){
          console.log(data)
        }
       });
    });
```

when the saveItem() run,the console log is array[],but the data named model in ajax is NULL?

Comment: You do realize that there's no such thing as associative arrays in javascript, and that you should be using an object (which is probably what you have now anyway)

Comment: try calling saveItem(id) before making the ajax request

Comment: You have to provide more information and a more complete example of your problem. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

"when the saveItem() run, ..." `saveItem` is never run. You've defined the function, but you haven't called it anywhere in your code. You probably meant it to be the success handler, instead of the handler you've got that just logs `data`. (Except that the argument to `saveItem` doesn't seem to match the argument supplied to the handler.)

Comment: *"when the saveItem() run,the console log is array[]"* sounds like the function is called somewhere.

Comment: There's a `console.log` in the success handler too.

Comment: Sure. But only because you don't see the function called doesn't mean it isn't (especially if the OP says that it is called). If you go in that direction, you also have to doubt whether `#submit_form` is clicked or whether it it exists at all.

Comment: You mean there might be another javascript file that OP forgot to tell us about? It's possible I suppose. I would have thought the function was scoped locally so it couldn't be called from anywhere else, but now that you mention it I'm not certain about that. In any case it's clear that OP is wrong about something (otherwise they wouldn't be here) and I don't think that forgetting to call a function would be particularly unlikely. What say you, wyvern? Have you called `saveItem` and forgotten to tell us?